# Inject sql/hql into spring bean using java configuration

Tags: java, spring

I have DAO

```
@Service
class MyDAO{
   private String hqlQuery;
   public List<String> getSomethingFromDB(){
      hibernate.doSomething(hqlQuery);
   }
}
```

And i would like keep definition of hql query in separate file. If i initialized this bean using xml i could do:

```
  <bean id="daoBEAN" class="myDAO">
     <property name="hqlQuery">
         <value><![CDATA[ some hql query  ]]></value>
     </property>
  </bean>
```

However how can I achieve something like this using Java configuration instead of XML confiuration?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Java configuration means you configure your application only from java code (with annotations mostly). To use you external file for setting value for a field has nothing to do with configuration type (be it xml or java based).

The simplest solution is to bind the query to your field from a property file.

```
@Repository
class MyDAO{

   @Value("${db-queries.get-persons}")
   private String sqlQuery;
   public List<String> getSomethingFromDB(){
      hibernate.doSomething(sqlQuery);
   }
}
```

and your **application.properties**:

```
db-queries.get-persons: SELECT * FROM PERSONS
```

or you can use **application.yml**  :

```
db-queries:
  get-persons: SELECT * FROM PERSONS
```

Note that I changed some typo in your code and made the example for sql query but it works even with hql .

Answer (score 0):

You can create configuration file(.properties) and have all hql queries.
Lets you have `application.properties` and create all properties start with name`hsql`.

```
  hsql.insertuser=<some queries>
```

Now create java class which read all properties.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("hsql")
public class AppProperties {

   private String insertUser;

  public String getInsertUser(){
    return this.insertUser;
  }
```

And your `DAO` class,

```
@Service
class myDAO{

@Autowired
 AppProperties myAppProperties;

   public List<Strin> getSomethingFromDB(){
      hibernate.doSomething(myAppProperties.getInsertUser());
   }
}
```

**Update**: If you want to have separate property file for queries then,

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:hsql.properties") 
@ConfigurationProperties
public class AppProperties {

   private String insertUser;

  public String getInsertUser(){
    return this.insertUser;
  }
```

Your `hsql.properties`

```
insertuser=<some queries>
```